# Presta valve problem

Tags: innertube, beginner

new to the Presta valve game, I just replaced my tube and the valve tore in less than 10 mins of riding. My bike tire is 26x1.9 the tube the got was 1.7-2.4. I have both the same rims and the front is also running a Presta valve. Not sure if I did something wrong or just a faulty tube.

Comment: Can you expand on the nature of the tear?  Is it torn in the butyl rubber right at the foot of the valve stem, or elsewhere?   Are your rims drilled for Presta or Schrader ?

Comment: If youtore the tube itself, it is more likely that it was installed incorrectly (irrespective of the valve type).

Comment: Did you  pull the valve all the way through the hole, and install the nut reasonably firmly (though not wrenched tight with pliers)?

Comment: I do not think the nut is necessary in any way. Many people just throw them away.

Comment: @VladimirF - The nut makes it possible to get the chuck on tight without damaging the tube.

Comment: @DanielRHicks As I wrote, many road cyclists just throw them away and manage just fine (rule 60). I use them, but always unscrew them before inflating when using tubes. Some tubes come with threadless valves anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A picture of the damage would tell for sure but 90% of the time tearing a valve - presta or schrader - is due to under inflation.

Low inflation pressure allows the tire to slip (during acceleration and/or braking on the rear, braking on the front) on the rim. The slipping tire rotates the tube. As the tube moves the valve is torn off as it moves against the valve hole in the rim.

It is possible to have a faulty tube. Usually defects (imperfections in molding etc.)look very different than forcibly tearing or cutting the valve on a tube.

Comment: Thanks so much , I returned the tube and they replaced it , the guy there said it was a faulty tube and replaced it right away. It’s a specialized airlock. Any tips to ensure a good tube install ?

Comment: As mentioned in other comments knowing exactly how the tube failed is important to understanding what you could have done differently.

Comment: @MattGrandy That would be a good question to post. Here's a link to a Park Tools video on installing tubes. https://youtu.be/eqR6nlZNeU8 Inspecting for damage happens at about 2 min 30 seconds. The install portion of the video happens at about 5 minutes 30 seconds.